# Как работать с exec?

Tags: php, exec

Здравствуйте.

Как прописывать команды в `exec()` и аргументы?

```
exec("env -i ".$config->get('path_php')." $cli test &>/dev/null &");
```

или

```
exec("fgh/gh -size 350x120 xc:black -font pointsize 70 -fill white -annotate +20+80 'текст' -trim +repage -bordercolor black -border 10 si57825b3af15b5.jpg");
```

Описание данной функции: [ссылка на мануал](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.exec.php)
Там об этом ни слова.

Comment: Так аргументы в exec разве не прописываются для внешней программы?

Comment: @ Doofy. Что вы имеете ввиду?

Comment: Внутри exec путь до запускаемой программы и аргументы для неё же

Comment: @Doofy. Какой алгоритм: вначале путь, потом аргументы? Как узнать какие аргументы прописывать, и как? Какие программы можно запускать?

Comment: Ну как это "ни слова"? Явно же написано: `command Команда (имя программы с аргументами - прим.пер.), которая будет исполнена.` "*Как узнать какие аргументы прописывать*" : `man progname`, `progname --help`, `google://progname` и т.д. "*Какие программы можно запускать?*" - какие фантазия подскажет.

Comment: @Pink Tux. _какие фантазия подскажет_. Разве текст является программой, и т.д.  Куда это вводить: _man progname, progname --help, google://progname_.

Comment: @Pink Tux.  `exec("text.txt");` какие параметры можно передать?  Какие программы можно запускать?

Comment: Можно и text.txt, если файл исполняемый, а внутри корректная программа. Де-факто вы можете запускать все консольные программы, которые доступны в системе пользователю, из под которого выполняется программа с exec(). Хотя в Windows и других оконных системах вы можете запускать exec() и графические программы. В unix-подобных системах такие программы сосредотачиваются в bin-каталогах. В современном UNIX их очень много, сотни и тысячи (часть идут по умолчанию, часть следует ставить).

Comment: @cheops Спасибо за ответ. Какой алгоритм вызова: имя программы или путь, потом аргументы через пробел? Аргументы: как ключ или как ключ значение через пробел? Есть ли где об этом можно прочитать подробнее, а так все ровно куча вопросов?

Comment: @Макс тема действительно большая, вы правы. Оформил ответ.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В документации PHP об этом упоминается вскольз, так как эта тема фактически выходит за рамки языка и интерпретатора, относясь к другим программам и операционной системе, где выполняется скрипт.

Де-факто вы можете запускать все консольные программы, которые доступны в системе пользователю, из под которого выполняется программа с `exec()`. Хотя в Windows и других оконных системах вы можете запускать `exec()` и графические программы. В unix-подобных системах такие программы сосредотачиваются в bin-каталогах. В современном UNIX их очень много, сотни и тысячи (часть идут по умолчанию, часть следует ставить).

Например, простейшая утилита просмотра текущего каталога `ls`, которая может принимать параметры `-l` (список) и `-a` (показывать все, в том числе скрытые файлы). Если дело происходит в Windows то вместо `ls -la` можно использовать команду `dir`

```
<?php
exec('ls -la', $output);
echo '<pre>';
print_r($output);
```

Вместо `exec()` чаще удобнее использовать `shell_exec()`

```
<?php
echo nl2br(shell_exec('ls -la'));
```

Или вовсе воспользоваться обратными кавычками

```
<?php
echo nl2br(`ls -la`);
```

Алгоритм формирования такой путь к программе или имя программы, если она доступна в командной строке без пути (прописана в переменной окружения PATH). Далее следует ноль, один или больше параметров программы. Формат параметра зависит от самой программы - что она ожидает в качестве параметров. В одних случаях вы указываете параметр предваряя его двумя дефисами

```
man --help
```

иногда дефис один

```
ls -h
```

Иногда несколько параметров могут сливаться в один

```
ls -l -a
ls -la
```

Иногда он вовсе отсутствует

```
eye i
```

Иногда после параметров могут идти значения, которые присваиваются параметрам

```
mysql -h localhost -u root -p
```

Как правило, двумя дефисами обозначают полное имя параметра, а одним — сокращенное

```
mysql --host localhost --user root --password
```

Какой формат параметров принят в каждой из команд нужно каждый раз изучать отдельно, за 40 лет каких только программ не по написали и жесткого стандарта нет.

В любой операционной системе очень много команд доступных в командной строке сразу после установки. Изучить их можно, изучая командную строку вашей операционной системы (даже в UNIX-подобных системах есть различия в параметрах, в Windows команды довольно сильно отличаются от UNIX-мира).

Вообще это действительно большая и интересная тема, которой посвящено не мало книг. В качестве отправной точки я бы посоветовал:

- Ричард Блум, Кристина Бреснахэн. Командная строка Linux и сценарии
  оболочки.
- Эрик C. Реймонд. Искусство программирования для Unix

Comment: Спасибо за развернутый ответ.